# How can I add proper indentation to this HTML generator that I wrote in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, depth-first-search

I wrote a function that takes in an object that represents the DOM tree and outputs HTML strings. I used a DFS approach to traverse the object.

```js
const tree = {
  children: [
    { children: [{ children: ['bar'], tag: 'span' }], tag: 'div' },
    { children: ['baz'], tag: 'div' },
  ],
  tag: 'body',
}

function fromTreeToString(root) {
  if (!root.children) {
    return root
  }
  return (
    `<${root.tag}>` + '\n' +
    `${root.children.map((node) => fromTreeToString(node)).join('\n')}` + '\n' +
    `</${root.tag}>`
  )
}

fromTreeToString(tree)
```

The output is

```
<body> 
<div> 
<span> 
bar 
</span> 
</div> 
<div> 
baz 
</div> 
</body>
```

I wonder how I can modify this function so that the output has a proper indentation to it. Ideally the output should look like

```
<body> 
  <div> 
    <span> 
      bar 
    </span> 
  </div> 
  <div> 
    baz 
  </div> 
</body>
```

and ideally the user of this API can customize the indentation e.g. tabs vs. space

Comment: @ggorlen right. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also first use recursion to return an *array* of lines, and only concatenate them at the end:

```js
function fromTreeToString(root, indent='\t') {
    const recur = root => root.children ? [
            `<${root.tag}>`, 
            ...root.children.flatMap(recur).map(s => indent + s),
            `</${root.tag}>`
        ] : root;
    return recur(root).join('\n');
}

const tree = {children: [{ children: [{ children: ['bar'], tag: 'span' }], tag: 'div' },{ children: ['baz'], tag: 'div' },],tag: 'body'}

console.log(fromTreeToString(tree, '. '));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! the flatMap trick is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a proper indentation to your function:

```
function fromTreeToString(root, indent) {
  indent = indent || '';

  if (!root.children) {
    return indent + root
  }
  return (
    `${indent}<${root.tag}>` + '\n' +
    `${root.children.map((node) => fromTreeToString(node, indent + '. ')).join('\n')}` + '\n' +
    `${indent}</${root.tag}>`
  )
}
```

Here, each recursion increases the indentation by `'. '`. The centre row in the template string is not indented directly. It gets its indentation from `indent + '. '` in the recursive call.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It seems like if you remove `.  ` and instead provide your own `indent` like `fromTreeToString(tree, '\t')` then the whole output is indented by a tab but it is not respecting the hierarchy. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you provide your own `indent`, tha's only the start of the indentaion. On lower levels, the (hard-coded) `'. '` will be added. If you want to make that configurable, you'll need another argument to the function. (The function is designed so that it doesn't change its signature from your original. I've used `'. '`, because it makes the indentaion more visible and I din't know whether multiple spaces would get collapsed into just one.)

Answer (score 0):

In this version you pass your indent string and get back a function that takes your tree structure and returns a formatted string:

```js
const fromTreeToString = (indent = '  ', depth = 0) => (node) =>
  `${indent.repeat(depth)}${node.tag ? `<${node .tag
  }>\n${(node.children || []).map(c => fromTreeToString(indent, depth + 1)(c)) .join ('\n')
  }\n${indent.repeat(depth)}</${node .tag}>` : node}`


const tree = {children: [{children: [{children: ['bar'], tag: 'span'}], tag: 'div'}, {children: ['baz'], tag: 'div'}, ], tag: 'body'}

const twoSpace = fromTreeToString('  ')
const fourSpace = fromTreeToString('    ')
const oneTab = fromTreeToString('\t')

console .log (twoSpace(tree))
console .log (fourSpace(tree))
console .log (oneTab(tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**Note** your title is misleading, as you are not *parsing* HTML but *formatting* it.

### Update

Here is a version without the higher-order function.  You can pass any indentation string you like.  If you don't pass it, you will get two spaces.

```js
const fromTreeToString = (node, indent = '  ', depth = 0) =>
  `${indent.repeat(depth)}${node.tag ? `<${node .tag
  }>\n${(node.children || []).map(c => fromTreeToString(c, indent, depth + 1)) .join ('\n')
  }\n${indent.repeat(depth)}</${node .tag}>` : node}`


const tree = {children: [{children: [{children: ['bar'], tag: 'span'}], tag: 'div'}, {children: ['baz'], tag: 'div'}, ], tag: 'body'}

console .log (fromTreeToString(tree, '  '))
console .log (fromTreeToString(tree, '    '))
console .log (fromTreeToString(tree, '\t'))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Can I ask why you made the original function a higher order function? can we just modify the original function to take a second parameter for `indent`?

Comment: You certainly can, but that requires you to supply the indentation on every call.  I would expect that in the end you'd prefer to call something like `myIndent (tree)` most of the time, and only rarely want to mess with the indent parameter.  But you could also add the indent (and depth) to the main function and default the indent with your preferred value.

Comment: I was trying to rewrite this without the higher order function but was having a hard time. Wondering if you can show me how to do it if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative answer using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Probably not something you *should* use, but you could. I was honestly just curious how it would play out

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const tree = { children: [{ children: [{ children: ['bar'], tag: 'span' }], tag: 'div' }, { children: ['baz'], tag: 'div' }], tag: 'body' };

const fn = (down) => ({ key, value, context }) => {
  if (value.constructor === Object) {
    context.push(`${' '.repeat(key.length / 2)}<${down ? '' : '/'}${value.tag}>`);
  } else if (down && typeof value === 'string') {
    context.push(`${' '.repeat(key.length / 2)}${value}`);
  }
};

const r = objectScan(['', '**(^children$)'], {
  reverse: false,
  useArraySelector: false,
  breakFn: fn(true),
  filterFn: fn(false)
})(tree, []).join('\n');

console.log(r);
/* =>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>
      bar
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    baz
  </div>
</body>
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)